# Cambiar color de un CHECKBOX en HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, bootstrap, checkbox

Tengo la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se requiere que cuando se marque la primera columna el check sea de color verde, si se marca la segunda sea de color rojo y si se marca la tercera sea de color naranja

mi codigo es el siguiente

```js
< script >
  $("input:checkbox").on('click', function() {

    var $box = $(this);
    if ($box.is(":checked")) {
      // set all elements matching the name to unchecked        
      $(this).closest('tr').find("input:checkbox[name='check_N2[]']").prop("checked", false)
      $(this).closest('tr').find("input:checkbox[name='check_N3[]']").prop("checked", false)

      // set the orginally checked box back to 'checked'       
      $box.prop("checked", true);
    } else {
      $box.prop("checked", false);
    }
  }); <
/script>
```

```html
<tr>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value_N2['id']; ?>" name="id_N2[]"> <strong><?php echo $value_N2['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
  <td style="text-align: justify;"><strong><?php echo $value_N2['descripcion']; ?> </strong></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_N2[]" checked disabled></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_N2[]" checked disabled></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check_N2[]" checked disabled></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $value_N3['id']; ?>" name="id_N3[]"> <strong><?php echo $value_N3['codigo']; ?> </strong></td>
  <td style="text-align: justify;">
    <?php echo $value_N3['descripcion']; ?>
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" value="1" name="check_N3[]"></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" value="2" name="check_N3[]" checked=""></td>
  <td style="text-align:center"><input type="checkbox" value="3" name="check_N3[]"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

**EL CHECKBOX QUE VIENE POR DEFAULT NO SE PUEDE CAMBIAR**
Pero podemos usar otras cosas a cambio:

Con el uso de CSS puedes crear custom checkboxes, y darles el color que quieras
Luego, puedes darles el color a cada uno de ellos llamandolos por ID.

```css
/* los checkboxes */
#c1 input:checked ~ .checkmark {
background-color: black;
}
#c2 input:checked ~ .checkmark {
background-color: red;
}
#c3 input:checked ~ .checkmark {
background-color: green;
}
#c4 input:checked ~ .checkmark {
background-color: blue;
}

/* Contenedor */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
}

/* escondemos el default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* creamos un custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* Al pasar el mouse encima, lo ponemos gris */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* creamos el marcador (escondido al no seleccionar) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* mostramos el marcador al seleccionar */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* estilo del marcador */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<label class="container" id="c1">Uno
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" id="c2">Dos
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" id="c3">Tres
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
<label class="container" id="c4">Cuatro
  <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
  <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que se necesita es cambiar el color del Check que ya está, no pintarlo de nuevo

Comment: Buena respuesta, creo que solo falta agregar que no es posible dar estilo directamente a checkboxes o radios, cada navegador los presenta en forma diferente y la única opción es sobreponer otro elemento. +1

Comment: Tal y como dice Triby, pense que habia quedado claro pero parece que no.

Answer (score 2):

Actualización 2023: desde 2021 existe la propiedad `accent-color` en CSS, que permite cambiar el color de acento de ciertos elementos: los `<input>` de  tipo `checkbox`, `radio` y `range`; y los `<progress>`. Esta propiedad se aplica directamente y se le indica un color, sin más:

```css
.accent-red {
    accent-color: red;
}

.accent-green {
    accent-color: #00ff00;
}

.accent-blue {
    accent-color: hsl(240deg, 100%, 50%);
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" class="accent-red" name="a" value="1">
<input type="radio" class="accent-green" name="a" value="2">
<input type="radio" class="accent-blue" name="a" value="3">
```